# Print unique names of users logged on with finger

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a shell script that prints the full names of users logged on to a machine. The finger command gives me a list of users, but there are many duplicates. How can I loop through and print out only the unique ones?

Edit:

This is the format of what finger gives me:

```
xxxx      XX of group XXX  pts/59   1:00  Feb 13 16:38 
xxxx      XX of group XXX  pts/71   1:11  Feb 13 16:27 
xxxx      XX of group XXX  pts/105    1d  Feb 12 15:22 
xxxx      YY of group YYY  pts/102  2:19  Feb 13 14:13 
xxxx      ZZ of group ZZZ  pts/42     2d  Feb  7 12:11
```

I'm trying to extract the full name (i.e. whatever comes before 'of group' in column 2), so I would be using awk together with finger.

Comment: can you paste some lines of your output? and what stuff do you want to extract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is actually fairly difficult in a shell script, here is, for example, my full output of `finger(1)`:

```
Login             Name             TTY      Idle  Login  Time   Office  Phone
martin            Martin Tournoij *v0         1d  Wed    14:11
martin            Martin Tournoij  pts/2      22  Wed    15:37
martin            Martin Tournoij  pts/5      41  Thu    23:16
martin            Martin Tournoij  pts/7      31  Thu    23:24
martin            Martin Tournoij  pts/8          Thu    23:29
```

You want the *full* name, but this may contain 1 space (as per my example), or it may just be 'Teller' (no space), or it may be 'Captain James T. Kirk' (3 spaces). So you can't just use the space as delimiter. You *could* use the character position of 'TTY' in the header as an indicator, but that's not very elegant IMHO (especially with shell scripting).

My solution is therefore slightly different, we get only the username from `finger(1)`, then we get the full name from `/etc/passwd`

```
#!/bin/sh

prev=""
for u in $(finger | tail +2 | cut -w -f1 | sort); do
        [ "$u" = "$prev" ] && continue
        echo "$u $(grep "^$u" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f5)"
        prev="$u"
done
```

Which gives me both the username & login name:

```
martin Martin Tournoij
```

Obviously, you can also print just the real name (without the `$u`).

Comment: Thanks! I did figure out how to do it with finger eventually, though it's not very elegant: `echo "finger -l"| awk '/Login/ {for (i=4; i<=NF && $i != "of"; i++) printf $i " "; print " "}' | sort`. I looked for the word "of" and printed whatever came before it.

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` and `uniq` BinUtils commands can be used to removed duplicates.

```
finger | sort -u
```

This will remove all duplicate lines, but you will still see similar lines due to how verbose the finger command is. If you just want a list of usernames, you can filter it out further to be very specific.

```
finger | cut -d ' ' -f1 | sort -u
```

Now, you can take this one step further, and remove the "header/label" line printed out by the `finger` command.

```
finger | cut -d ' ' -f1 | sort -u | grep -iv login
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or just `finger | cut -d ' ' -f1 | ( read; sort -u )` ... especially if you could have users named `flogint` or whatever.

Comment: Does not answer the question. He wants the full name.

Answer (score 1):

Other possible solution:

```
finger | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort | uniq
```

- `tail -n +2` to omit the first line.
- `awk '{ print $1 }'` to extract the first column.
- `sort` to prepare input for `uniq`.
- `uniq` remove duplicates.

If you want to iterate use:

```
for user in $(finger | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort | uniq)
do
    echo "$user"
done
```

Comment: if awk is there, usually other tools could be saved.

Comment: I am a newbie in `awk` (well, with the other tools too :)).

Comment: Does not answer the question. He wants the full name.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be simpler?
No spaces or any other special characters to worry about!

```
finger -l | awk '/^Login/'
```

**Edit**: To remove the content after `of group`

```
finger -l | awk '/^Login/' | sed 's/of group.*//g'
```

Output:

```
Login: xx                          Name: XX
Login: yy                          Name: YY
Login: zz                          Name: ZZ
```

Comment: This still gives me the group after the name though.

Comment: @mcglashan how about then pipe it to `sed 's/of group.*//g'`